# How to fit a logistic distribution use a fixed location parameter?

Tags: scipy, logistic-regression, curve-fitting, distribution, mle

I use `scipy.stats.logistic.fit()` with fixed location value, to get an estimated scale parameter, while the residual does not hold normality from qqplot.

How should I improve it and how to visualize the errors? Is there other way to estimated the parameters for a logistic distribution?

For the data I used: `shape (1000,150)`, the histogram shows a slightly right-tailed. use the maximum value in the dataset as location, and to estimate the parameter of scale.

---

Here is the code I used:

```
datalogitic= np.loadtxt(f"datalogiticfit.txt")
data=datalogitic[:,:51].flatten()
loc=data.max()
loc_lower=loc
loc_upper=loc
scale_lower=0
scale_upper=1000

dist = stats.logistic
bounds = [(loc_lower, loc_upper), (scale_lower,scale_upper)]
result = stats.fit(dist, data,bounds,method='mle')
print("Parameters of the Logistic Distribution are : ", result.params)
result.plot()
plt.show()

x = np.linspace(data.min(), data.max(), len(data))
cdf = stats.logistic.cdf(x, loc=result.params[0], scale=result.params[1])
plt.plot(x, cdf, label='Logistic CDF (Estimated Parameters)')
ecdf = ECDF(data)
plt.plot(ecdf.x, ecdf.y, label='Empirical CDF', linestyle="dashdot")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

When I looked at PDF of logistic provided in the page of
`scipy.stats.logistic`:

```
f(x) = \frac{\exp(-x)}
       {(1+\exp(-x))^2}
```

The denominator part is not the same as found in the book **Handbook of the Logistic Distribution (Statistics a Series of Textbooks and Monographs) (N. Balakrishnan)**.

```
f(x,u,s) = \frac{\exp(-(x-u)/s)}
           {s*(1+\exp(-(x-u)/s)))^2}
```

Or they are equivalent?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Without code, it's hard to help. Please include fully executable code including imports and data. A common mistake is to think that passing the `loc` partameter fixes the location, but that specifies a *guess*. `floc` is used to fix the location.

Comment: Note that the `logistic.fit` method is not the default numerical optimization; it is overridden to solve an equation, so it should be quite reliable. That said, `logistic.fit` can fail, but we'd need data to tell. Another option is maximum product spacing with `scipy.ststs.fit` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.fit.html.

Comment: @Community i updated a code screenshot. thank you.

Comment: @MattHaberland Thank you. Yes, i used (floc). Also tried the alternative as you suggested, it is can be fixed if i use bounds. Do you have any suggestion to choose the bound for scale parameter?

Comment: Do **not** post images of code. See bullet item #3 under [Help others reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the site’s help center.

Comment: Wikipedia shows a simple analytical relationship between the variance and scale parameter. If you set the variance equal to sample variance and solve for scale, that should give you a good guess. Maybe make the bounds an order of magnitude above and below that. Can you post data, though? `logistic.fit` is not supposed to fail when location is fixed.

Comment: @MattHaberland fitting is not failed, it does give estimated scale value, however, the fitting performs not good, if i look at the residual plot. Also my another question is how you evaluate the fitting performance? for data,  i think i should not post it, sorry for this inconvenience.

Comment: `logistic.fit` uses maximum likelihood estimation (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation), a very standard technique, by default. You said the `scipy.stats.fit` meets your needs? If so, can you improve the question by posting the code as text rather than an image so it can be reopened, then I can provide that as the answer? This would help others in the future.

Comment: @MattHaberland Thank you for the help. i updated the code. yes only if i set the scale bound manually, otherwise, the fitting is terrible. i wonder how you define the bound for parameters, i.e what information i should look for from data?  If this fitting procedure could add an evaluation methods in the end would be great. For example, in my case i would like to use qqplot for residual and chi-square goodness of fit to test.

Comment: Why are you fixing the location to the maximum observed value? That is going to produce a poor fit because the location should be close to the mean. Also, your two formulas for the PDF are for the same distribution. Read the note in the SciPy documentation that begins "The probability density above is defined in the “standardized” form." Chi-square is goodness of fit is appropriate for discrete distributions; you should be using one for continuous distributions.

Comment: Can you add the Q-Q plot you're getting to the post so we can see why you say it is poor? Also, can you clarify what you mean by "residual does not hold normality from qqplot"? Do you just mean that the Q-Q plot does not look like there is a good fit, or something more specific about the distribution of the differences between the fitted distribution and observed data? I can't answer until the post is re-opened.

Comment: @MattHaberland thank you for your answer. i reset the bounds which will include mean. but how to evaluate the goodness of fit?

Comment: @MattHaberland yes , you are right, i made a mistake. i followed your steps, also add a k-s test, it fits not good. But thank you so much, i can understand this much better!

Comment: Great. Please remember to either write your own answer or accept one of the ones here so future visitors with similar issues know what to read.

Answer (score 0):

Lets create a synthetic dataset:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats, optimize

np.random.seed(123456)

law = stats.logistic(loc=1.2, scale=2.3)
data = law.rvs(30000)
```

You can fit with fixed parameters:

```
stats.logistic.fit(data, floc=1.2)
# (1.2, 2.30433453917283)
```

If you want to perform MLE by yourself, just state the likelihood:

```
def factory(x, loc=0.):
    def wrapped(p):
        return - stats.logistic(loc=loc, scale=p[0]).logpdf(x).sum()
    return wrapped

likelihood = factory(data, loc=1.2)

sol = optimize.minimize(likelihood, x0=[1])
#   message: Optimization terminated successfully.
#   success: True
#    status: 0
#       fun: 85067.14024628093
#         x: [ 2.304e+00]
#       nit: 7
#       jac: [ 0.000e+00]
#  hess_inv: [[ 1.238e-04]]
#      nfev: 16
#      njev: 8
```

Which also provides you uncertainty on parameter estimation (`hess_inv`).

Comment: For me, hess_inv: [[ 3.640e+02]] . Is it not okay?

Answer (score 0):

> Or they are equivalent?

Yes. One is specific to location and variance of zero and one, respectively; the other includes them as parameters. Read the note in the [SciPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.logistic.html) that begins "The probability density above is defined in the “standardized” form."

> How should I improve it

Don't fix the location to the maximum of the data. If the location is truly known, fix it to the known value; if not, include it as a free parameter when fitting. The location of the distribution is its median, so 50% of the observations you'd draw would be less than the location. Therefore, the probability of all `N` observations being less than or equal to the location parameter is `1/2**N`. Also, ignoring rounding due to double precision, the probability of an observation *exactly* matching the location parameters is zero. So if you think you know the location parameter, and if it *happens* to equal the maximum value of the data, I'd suggest checking your assumptions or your data collection; something is wrong.

> and how to visualize the errors?

To visualize the errors, you can create several different plots after fitting with [`scipy.stats.goodness_of_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.goodness_of_fit.html). See the `plot` method of [`FitResult`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats._result_classes.FitResult.html#scipy.stats._result_classes.FitResult).

> Is there other way to estimated the parameters for a logistic distribution?

Yes, there are three ways that are easily done in SciPy:

- [maximum likelihood estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation), which can be performed using either `scipy.stats.fit` or [`scipy.stats.logistic.fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit),
- [maximum spacing estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_spacing_estimation), which can be performed using `scipy.stats.fit` with `method='mse'`, and
- [method of moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(statistics)), which can be performed using `scipy.stats.logistic.fit`, but it's easy enough to do analytically, so I've gone ahead and done that in the code.

Method of L-moments is also possible, but it requires [custom code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/19460#issuecomment-1793547120).

Here is some code to fit the distribution, produce a Q-Q plot, and check goodness of fit using [`scipy.stats.goodness_of_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.goodness_of_fit.html).

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
rng = np.random.default_rng(238923498234)

dist_family = stats.logistic

# simulate real data, which is not necessarily distributed
# according to logistic distribution.
loc, scale = 1.25, 3.25
data = rng.normal(loc=loc, scale=scale, size=1000)

# For guessing the parameters, use method of moments, which
# sets the parameters such that the distribution moments match
# the sample moments.

# Location was fixed in OP's original problem, so I'm fixing
# it here. However, in case a guess is needed, note that the
# distribution moment is equal to the location parameter.
sample_mean = np.mean(data)
l = sample_mean
# verify that they match
np.testing.assert_allclose(dist_family(loc=l).mean(), sample_mean)

# To get a guess of scale parameter, set the expression
# for the distribution variance equal to the sample variance
# and solve for the scale parameter.
sample_var = np.var(data, ddof=1)
s = np.sqrt(3*sample_var/np.pi**2)
# verify that they match
np.testing.assert_allclose(dist_family(loc=loc, scale=s).var(), sample_var)

# Fit using `logistic.fit`, fixing location at `loc` and
# providing `s` as a guess of the scale
params0 = dist_family.fit(data, floc=loc, scale=s)

# fit using `stats.fit`
bounds = {'loc': (loc, loc),
          'scale': (s/10, s*10)}  # usually sufficiently loose
dist = stats.fit(dist_family, data, bounds=bounds)
# consider trying `method=mse` for maximum product spacing estimate

# Check for agreement between `logistic.fit` and `stats.fit`
np.testing.assert_allclose(dist.params, params0)

# Produce Q-Q plot
dist.plot(plot_type='qq')

# Test goodness of fit using Anderson-Darling (AD) test
# Other methods are available; see documentation. 
# Use `known_params` to fix parameters are truly known;
# use `fit_parameters` for those that are fitted to data
res = stats.goodness_of_fit(dist_family, data,
                            known_params={'loc': loc},
                            fit_params={'scale': dist.params[1]},
                            statistic='ad')

res
# GoodnessOfFitResult(fit_result=params: FitParams(loc=1.25, scale=1.8552584333141091)
#                     success: True
#                     message: 'The fit was performed successfully.',
#                     statistic=1.5959097382901746, pvalue=0.1199, 
#                     null_distribution=array([0.28497412, 0.59373208, 0.86174867, ..., 0.69325478, 0.97925162, 1.70976138]))
```

[image]